# How can I clean up all custom apt repositories?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, repository, software-sources

When I look in my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory, I have the following files:

```
bazel.list
bazel.list.save
deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list
google-cloud-sdk.list
google-cloud-sdk.list.save
```

Whenever I run `sudo apt update`, I get a bunch of errors related to the Bazel and Google Cloud repos, e.g.

```
An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the
previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk
InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:
NO_PUBKEY xxx NO_PUBKEY xxx
```

Rather than trying to fix that error, I really just want to wipe out all custom Apt sources and PPAs - I am also having some issues with the deadsnakes PPA interfering with system Python.

**My question: What steps do I need to take to completely remove custom Apt sources from my Ubuntu installation?**  Is it enough to just delete the files in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory?    Should I also run `sudo add-apt-repository --remove`?  Are there GPG or other keys stored somewhere that I need to purge?

I did see [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed), which gives me a clue about how to remove the deadsnakes PPA, but I'm still not sure about the Google lists.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS on WSL 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the terminal run:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.list.old

sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list.old
```

This will disable each repository file. You can then edit them and rename them back if you should like to do so in the future.

Answer (score 3):

- Open the tool "Software & Updates"
- Head to the second tab, "Other Software".
- Remove the checkmark before a source to disable it;  select a software source and use the "Remove" button to completely remove the source.
- Hit the "Close" button when done.